# Angular : How to use app.tick() ? Can anyone give me an example of ApplicationRef.tick()?

Tags: angular

When we talk about Change Detection mechanism in Angular 2, everyone suggests using `NgZone` or `ChangeDetectorRef`.

Is there any working example of `application.tick()`/`ApplicationRef.tick()` which also does the same thing as `ChangeDetectorRef`/`NgZone`.

**Second question**: API says, in DEV MODE, `ApplicationRef.tick()` runs the change detection more than once.

Is there a way to run it only once. Because the moment I use this method, I get an error saying

> **ApplicationRef.tick() is called recursively**

Similar example of the problem I face using tick() is here [in this Github Link](https://github.com/blackbaud/skyux2/issues/744)

I have gone through [Triggering Change Detection Manually Question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827334/triggering-angular2-change-detection-manually)

Any info in this appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

### First of all what is **ApplicationRef**?

> Application Ref contains reference to the root view and can be used to
> manually run change detection using tick function.

### So how do we use the `tick()` function?

Inject it into your component constructor and use it as you wish!

---

**N.B.** I purposely entered the **ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush** to remove the automatic update, so we should force the application to update manually.

In this regard we will use `Tick()` function !

---

**SIMPLE TEST CASE:**

**component.ts**

```
@Component ({
   selector: 'my-app',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
   changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class AppComponent {
   ...
   counter = 1;

   constructor (private appRef: ApplicationRef) {
     setInterval (() => this.counter ++, 1000);
   }

   updateApplication () {
     this.appRef.tick ();
   }
}
```

**component.html**

```
<h1>{{counter}}</h1>

<button (click)="updateApplication()"> UPDATE APP </button>
```

---

In my example every time we click on the **UPDATE APP** button we call the `tick()` function which **updates every single child component starting from the application root**.

So in our case it will simply update the counter variable.

[Stackblitz Test Case](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vmfqpt)

---

As for your **second question**, if you can avoid having the `tick()` called twice in `devMode` the answer is **You can't avoid it**!

But I don't think this behavior leads to a **recursive** call, most likely you have used the function incorrectly, grafting components that call the `tick()` or not disabling the **changeDetection** so as to start two or more **changeDetects** together.

Comment: If I comment out  this.appRef.tick (); line still the the view is updating on click of button.

Comment: Yes, it's a bad example, the DOM click event will trigger a ChangeDetection.

Answer (score 8):

`ApplicationRef.tick()` calls `setTimeout((){})`

You should only need this when code that runs outside Angulars zone updates Angulars model and Angular therefore can't get notified about the change by `NgZone`.

It just invokes change detection for the whole application.
Usually it's better wrapping the code that updates the model from the outside with `zone.run(() => {...})` than using `ApplicationRef.tick()`

`ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` or `ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()` act only on a specific element (and its descendants).

To clarify for a comment below how to get `zone`:

```
class MyComponent {
  constructor(private zone:NgZone) {}

  foo() {
    ...
    this.zone....
  }
}
```

Comment: Günter Zöchbauer - Can you tell me what is the connection between ApplicationRef.tick() and setTimeout(() {}) ? Is it like running setting timeout on change detection mechanism  or something else?

Comment: `setTimeout` is recognized by `NgZone` and just invokes normal change detection.

Comment: Günter Zöchbauer - Thanks for clearing this out. Can you answer my question too w.r.t to recursion? Will it resolve with setTimeout?

Comment: At first I would need the information why you think you need `ApplicationRef.tick()` in the first place. As I wrote, it's rather uncommon that you need it. If it causes an endless loop, there is probably some other problem in your code. For example if you bind to a function in your components template which will be called every time change detection runs.

Comment: Yes, I am doing the very same thing as you stated in the example. But that's the business requirement. How can I go around in a case like that?

Comment: Actually, I still don't know why you think you need to use `ApplicationRef.tick()`

Comment: I have a binding to a function in my component template which is getting called to change the values, every time user clicks on each of the items. Now, this doesn't work without ApplicationRef.tick(). Hence, trying to find a work around to it.

Comment: Binding a function to an event is perfectly fine. What I meant is binding a function to a property/attribute whis is most of the time a very bad idea. You definitely shouldn't need ApplicationRef.tick()` fo code that is called from a `(click)="..."`

Comment: yeah but how do you import zone? you need to provide a full example. I have no way of knowing how to implement this.

Comment: `NgZone` is from `@angular/core` and you inject it using the constructor: `constructor(private zone:NgZone) {}`

Comment: Instead of providing an example on how to use NgZone, could someone provide an example of how to use app.tick()?

Comment: `markForCheck` will also mark the parents.